# *87 connect() to unix:///home/ubuntu/app_name/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, puma, rbenv

I am trying to deploy a `rails 7` application on `aws-lightsail` `unbuntu 20.04` instance using `capistrano3` gem. After deployment, I see `502 bad gateway` nginx page in browser. When I check `puma_error.log`, log says that `connection to puma.sock was refused`.

I ran `ps ax | grep puma` to check if puma is running but nothing shows up. I restarted puma by `cap production puma:restart` and it shows puma has successfully started and daemaonized.

```
shoaib:report shoaib$ cap production puma:restart
00:00 puma:start
      using conf file /home/ubuntu/app_name/shared/puma.rb
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec puma -C /home/ubuntu/app_name/shared/puma.rb --daemon
      01 * Pruning Bundler environment
      01
      01 [DEPRECATED] `Bundler.with_clean_env` has been deprecated in favor of `Bundler.with_unbundled_env`. If you instead want the environment before bundl…
      01
      01 [214552] Puma starting in cluster mode...
      01
      01 [214552] * Version 3.12.6 (ruby 3.1.2-p20), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
      01
      01 [214552] * Min threads: 0, max threads: 8
      01
      01 [214552] * Environment: production
      01
      01 [214552] * Process workers: 2
      01
      01 [214552] * Phased restart available
      01
      01 [214552] * Listening on unix:///home/ubuntu/app_name/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
      01
      01 [214552] * Daemonizing...
      01
    ✔ 01 ubuntu@3.12.163.170 1.922s
```

But when i run `cap production puma:status`, it says puma not running.

```
shoaib:report shoaib$ cap production puma:status
00:00 puma:status
      WARN  Puma not running
```

In addition, no `puma.pid` file is being created in `/tmp/pids/` directory on server. Can someone please point me in the right direction as I already have spent many hours on it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by switching to `rvm` from `rbenv` on my server instance. The problem was `rbenv` not identifying application's `current` directory as a `rails` application thus not invoking `rails s` command on it. When I ran `rails s -e production` in app's current directory, only the template of rails command was printed in response.

So switching to `rvm` solved the issue for me. I am still clueless on `rbenv` behaviour that caused this issue.